# How to insert same data into multiple tables in mysql using triggers

Tags: mysql

i have created two tables into student database

1) **Admission table** (rollNO,Name,fname,address,department,addmission_date)

2) **Fees Table**(rollNO,Name,fname,address,department,Total_fees,Fees_Payment_date)

i want to insert same data of addmission table into fees table which contain same column names like **rollNO,Name,fname,address,department** using trigger's event "**after**"

how can i do it? if i insert data into addmission table it will also automatically insert into fees table????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, `NEW` is ref of `admission` table insert record contains

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `fee_trigg` AFTER INSERT ON `admission`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO fee  (rollNO,Name,fname,address,department)
   VALUES( NEW.rollNO, NEW.Name, NEW.fname,NEW.address,NEW.department );
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```